# How to resize a PIL.ImageTk image?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm making a GUI with `Tkinter` and `Sqlite`. In it there is a button that says show photos. When user click that button it displays an image which stored in db file as binary-BLOB-. So far so good but when it comes a large sized image I have to resize the window all the time. So the question is how to resize an `ImageTk.PhotoImage` object to desired size so that I can display every image without thinking how big they are.

Here is the code:

```
mydb= sqlite3.connect('customers.db')
cursor = mydb.cursor()


sql_fetch_blob_query = """SELECT * from foto """
records=cursor.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query)
records = cursor.fetchall()

fotoframe=tk.Toplevel()
fotoframe.title("Title")
fotoframe.geometry("500x500")
img=[]

for record in records:
    #base64_encoded= base64.b64encode(record[0])
    #base64_encoded_string= base64_encoded.decode('utf-8')
    #fotoimg= PIL.Image.open(base64_encoded)

    imgobject=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(data= record[0])
    #imgobject = imgobject.resize((450, 350), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

    img.append(imobject)# record[0] is definitely binary data I'm looking for.
                         # I have tried all of the comment rows above in this for loop but could not 
                         # figure it out
    
foto_label= tk.Label(fotoframe,image=img[0])
foto_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)


fotoframe.mainloop()
```

I don't get errors from this code but like I said I want my window size stay 500x500.

If an image comes sized bigger than that I want to shrink it to my window.Is there a possible way to do that? Have been looking for docs for a time but all I saw was about`Image` class not `ImageTk`. Again I am aware of the `resize` method but it is `Image` classes method.

Comment: You may be able to first create a PIL `Image` object by using [`Image.frombytes()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes) and then resize it before turning it into a `ImageTk.PhotoImage`.

Comment: It really depends on the format of the BLOB data.  Try `image = Image.open(BytesIO(record[0]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an integer conversion (exactly half or exactly double) you can use the PhotoImage zoom() or subsample() methods. Otherwise you will need to load the data into PIL to calculate the resize.

You have the right idea about decoding the base64 data. Once that's done you can pass it into PIL's Image via a BytesIO object (a fake file).

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from base64 import b64decode
from io import BytesIO

TARGET_SIZE = (256, 256)

# blah blah your other code

for record in records:
    image_data = record[0]
    loaded_img = Image.open(BytesIO(b64decode(image_data)))
    resized_img = loaded_img.resize(TARGET_SIZE)
    photo_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_img)
    img.append(photo_img)
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't had to use `b64decode`. Instead of I used just `image_data` and it worked well. Thanks @Novel